# Is silicon a semiconductor or insulator?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, material-science, solar-cells

I have read that pure crystalline silicon is an insulator because it has a such covalent bond that very tight and no free electrons available for conduction bands. They all are bonded with other silicon atoms with a covalent bond. I also have read that they make silicon a semiconductor only by doping it.

However, in other sources silicon is counted along with semiconductors such as germanium and tin.

How so?

Comment: You mean grey tin. There are two forms of tin.

Comment: Only at absolute zero does pure silicon have no electrons in the conduction band or holes in the valence band. At room temperature, intrinsic silicon has about $10^{10}$/cm$^{3}$ carriers. Not a lot, but measurable conduction occurs.

Comment: It depends on the definition of these two categories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Physics, it is meaningless to ask if a particular substance is an insulator, a semiconductor, or a metal as far as the electronic transport is concerned.

The reason is that the electronic properties of a material do depend on its chemical composition, but also on its thermodynamic phases and states.

Let's take the example of silicon (but any other material would be equally good). There are different equilibrium phases of crystalline silicon, depending on temperature and pressure.

From Wippermann, S., He, Y., Vörös, M., & Galli, G. (2016). *Novel silicon phases and nanostructures for solar energy conversion.* [Applied Physics Reviews, 3(4), 040807](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4961724):

> Under pressure, bulk Si retains its cubic diamond (cd, Si-I) structure up to ∼11.7 GPa.1 At higher pressure, Si-I transforms into the metallic β-tin phase (Si-II), whose stability interval is rather small. On further pressure increase beyond ∼15 GPa, the β-tin phase transforms first into an orthorhombic Imma phase, and then into a simple hexagonal one (sh, Si-V). Above 42 GPa, a hexagonal close-packed (hcp) solid has been observed, with the orthorhombic Cmca phase (Si-VI) formed as an intermediate within 40–42 GPa. At 78 GPa, a face-centered cubic (fcc) solid is obtained, which remains stable up the highest presently investigated pressure of ∼250 GPa.

It is clear that the same atoms, with the same electronic properties, may produce very different electronic behavior. And this variety is even larger if one considers the possible presence, in real materials, of different kinds of defects and surface and size effects. And, of course, there is also the liquid phase.

Under normal pressure, the stable crystalline phase of the diamond lattice. Within such a structure, the electronic transport properties still depend on temperature.

Here, the classification as an insulator, semiconductor, or metal becomes more meaningful, although it requires a careful scrutiny of the definition one is using. The definition based on the presence of an energy gap between the highest occupied electronic band and the lowest unoccupied band is sharp only by reference to the zero temperature case. At finite temperature, there will be a fraction of the electrons populating states above the gap. In such a case, any distinction between semiconductors and insulators becomes quantitative and strongly depending on the threshold one is using.

According to this definition, there is no doubt that pure crystalline silicon is a semiconductor. However, a probably better definition is to state that a semiconductor shows some conduction (like a metal) but, at variance with the metal, the conductivity *increases* with temperature (in the metals, it decreases). One of the reasons such a definition is better is that it accommodates quite simply the case of zero-gap semiconductors. According to this definition, there is no doubt that pure crystalline silicon is a semiconductor.

The final lesson of such an analysis is that physics is not simply a set of static definitions. In order to classify a physical system, it is required to understand the reasons and the limits of definitions.

Comment: I agree that properties depend on state. For example, liquid silicon is a metal. Nevertheless it is **quite clear** that the OP is asking about solid crystalline silicon.

Comment: @my2cts, I agree, and I think that he had In mind normal pressure and room temperature. Still, I feel fundamental to avoid the misconception that some physical properties are properties of the atomic species independent of the state. It is similar to the naive idea that objects made by dense material must always sink :-)

Comment: Indeed and it doesn't help that astronomers call any atom heavier than helium a metal.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between semiconductors and insulators is a quantitative rather than a qualitative one. The principal division here is between the insulators and the metals: the former have the last band with electrons completely filled (*valence band*), and the first unfilled band completely empty (*conduction band*). In metals the last band with electrons is only partially filled - this electrons can be easily excited by an electric field, which is why metals are good conductors. On the other hand, driving current through an insulator requires transferring electrons from the valence band to the conduction band, across the gap of energy $E_g$.

In semiconductors this gap energy is comparable to temperature, which makes them conducting at room temperature, as some electrons are thermally excited to the conduction band (and some states in the valence band are vacant). In insulators the gap is much bigger, and they are non-conducting.

**Update**
I recommend checking out [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimetal#/media/File:Band_filling_diagram.svg) from the [Wikipedia article on semimetals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimetal). The distinction between a metal and semimetal is quantitative, just as the distinction between a semiconductor and insulator, however the distinction between the former two and the latter two is qualitative (Fermi level in the gap).

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll The gap of Si is small enough to have it called semiconductor. One can say that diamond is a wide gap semiconductor, too.

Comment: @alchimista Why is there a confusion? Simply the question is : "Is silicon a semiconductor or insulator?"

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll because the difference is quantitative. As per Wikipedia its resistivity at RT is 2.3 10^3 ohm m.

Comment: Then why do some sources count crystalline pure silicon as insulators rather than semiconductors? @Alchimista

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll because is matter of what one focus on. A practical resistivity (which is high) or the underlying principle. Polystyrene is an insulator independent of any consideration.

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll Semiconductors *are* insulators with a small band gap. What you say in the OP - that the covalent bonds are saturated - is the reason why no electrons are mobile, i.e., why it is an insulator. Doping introduces additional charge carriers (electrons and holes) that make semiconductors conducting even at very low temperatures... they essentially become metallic.

Comment: @PhysicsSolvesAll A crude analogy to your question "why the confusion?" is everything becomes a conductor under the right conditions (i.e. high voltage).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one shocking fact:

- All insulators, unless they are at absolute zero temperature, conduct at least a little bit of electricity.

Metals conduct electricity because they have a band, called the conduction band, which is half-full of electrons, and these can move freely within the conduction band, thus conducting electricity.

In insulators, there is also a conduction band, but (as a first approximation) it is empty. This conduction band is separated from the valence band by a nonzero energy gap $E_g$, and the valence band is completely full, so electrons cannot move inside it.

However, note the qualifier: *as a first approximation*. If you want those statements to be exactly true, then you need to cool the insulator down to zero thermodynamic temperature. In the real world, at temperature $T$, there will be some (probably quite small) probability for a few electrons to be thermally excited to the conduction band, where they can conduct electricity. As a ballpark figure, this probability is
$$
p = e^{-E_g/k_B T},
$$
where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant. That means that you have two relevant cases:

- If $E_g/k_B T$ is large (i.e. for a wide-bandgap insulator, or if the insulator is very cold), then $p$ will be vanishingly small, and you can basically ignore the few electrons in the conduction band.
- On the other hand, if $E_g/k_B T$ is small (i.e. if the bandgap is small, or if you heat up the insulator), then $p$ will start to grow, and you'll get more and more electrons to play with.

Semiconductors are insulators that are closer to the second endpoint than the first one, so they do conduct *some* current. However, it's a subjective, sliding scale, and there is no meaningful objective point that separates "pure" insulators from "pure" semiconductors. And, moreover, there is no such thing as "pure" insulators or "pure" semiconductors to begin with: insulators and semiconductors are the same thing, and the distinction is just a subjective separation based on what end of the scale they sit, and at what temperature we're interested in.

In other words, if you're looking for a single bright-line answer to the question as you posed it, there isn't one. Silicon is both a semiconductor and an insulator (as are all semiconductors and insulators). Deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could call silicon an insulator but you would have to add 'with a small bandgap'. The short expression for that is 'semiconductor'. The small bandgap also leads to some, temperature dependent, conductivity  at room temperature for intrinsic silicon, to photovoltaic and photoelectric properties. If silicon is not very pure then it will show defect-related conductivity as well. So not a metal, not an insulator, hence a semiconductor.

[At the time that this terminology was developed quantum mechanics and band theory did not yet exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor#Early_history_of_semiconductors). It was a phenomenological term for a class of materials with conductivity in between conductors and insulator, and with photoconductivity and photovoltaic properties as well as a conductivity that increases with temperature.
There also exist [semimetals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimetal). These have a small overlap between conduction and valence band.

Perhaps superfluous, 'semi' is greek for half.

You'll notice the pattern.